# Google Calendar not recognizing EXDATES that aren't on the hour?

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm generating an ics that should ignore events on holidays, and using the EXDATE parameter to accomplish this.

My code works in Outlook, which just needs to date for EXDATE, but Google Calendar requires that the time be present as well.

Unfortunately, Google Calendar isn't recognizing my EXDATES for events that occur after noon.

```
    while(start < end)
    {
        if(iSholiday(new Date(start)))
        {
        //Google Calendar only recognizes the Exdate parameter if it's at the same time as the regular event.
        start.setHours(eventTime.getHours(), eventTime.getMinutes());   
        exDateStr += start.toISOString() +','; //Of the format 2015-09-07T17:40:00.000Z
    }
    //Advance day to tomorrow
    start = new Date(start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1));
```

Again, this works for events that occur in the morning, but not ones that occur after noon.

**EDIT :**
I have it returning the correct dates, but still only acting as if the ones before noon should be ignored.

Pictured: each of my exdate strings. Only the 8:00 and the 11:00 work
    [image: enter code here]

Pictured: Other exdate strings that (presumably) work with Google Calendar.
[image]

**EDIT 2** I've also noticed that all of my events after noon have minutes, while the ones in the morning do not. It seems that Google isn't recognizing events that do not occur on the hour.

**EDIT 3** I've included my RRULE.

```
var rule = {
    freq: "WEEKLY",
    until: new Date(end.setHours(1,0)),
};
```

...[ommited code]

```
        var calendarEvent = [
            'BEGIN:VEVENT',
            'CLASS:PUBLIC',
            'TZID:US/Central', //Force Central
            'DESCRIPTION:' + description,
            'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:' + start,
            'DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:' + end,
            'LOCATION:' + location,
            'SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:' + subject,
            'EXDATE;TZID=US-Central:' + exdates,  //Force Central, exdates is a formatted string containing dates to skip (Holidays), as per the RRUle standard.
    'TRANSP:TRANSPARENT',
            'END:VEVENT'
        ];
       ];

        if (rruleString) {
          calendarEvent.splice(4, 0, rruleString);//Example: RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20151212T000000Z;BYDAY=TU,TH
        }

        calendarEvent = calendarEvent.join(SEPARATOR);

        calendarEvents.push(calendarEvent);
        return calendarEvent;
    },
```

**EDIT 4** I've included the Vcalendar for the 12:40 event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
TZID:US/Central
DESCRIPTION:Class
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20151212T000000Z;BYDAY=TU,TH
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150825T124040
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150825T140000
LOCATION:MOL-BIO  1414  
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:COM S 311 
EXDATE;TZID=US-Central:20150907T124000000,20151123T124000000,20151124T124000000,20151125T124000000,20151126T124000000,20151127T124000000
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Would you mind also showing the RRULE of the event to which you are adding these EXDATEs?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: EXDATE stands for an exception from a recurrence rule. Your event does not have any recurrence rule so it is surprising you are trying to exclude dates. Did you want to use RRULE and RDATE instead? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I propose you also add a full VCALENDAR output of this string magic (for the :40 case). I'm in particularly interested in the start value and whether the EXDATEs are correctly pointing to the starts of valid instances of this event.

Comment: Apologies for the delay; I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ics.js fork that I was using had the line

```
  var start_seconds = ("00" + (start_date.getMinutes().toString())).slice(-2);
```

instead of

```
  var start_seconds = ("00" + (start_date.getSeconds().toString())).slice(-2);
```

Which was causing the start time to be 12:10:10 instead of 12:10:00. Thanks to user Luc for helping me find the problem!